# Issue with VBA - Copying from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'll preface this by saying I'm a complete novice to VBA but not coding. I'm trying to write part of a VBA script that can copy data from one worksheet in another workbook to a pre-existing worksheet in another workbook.

I'm trying to make use of dynamic ranges as I know the starting point for the data every time however my issues comes when it comes to the copying. The code runs up to the point of the copy where it stagnates with no error codes. Effectively gets stuck in stasis requiring user action.

```vb
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requisitions Raised")
Set StartCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requisitions Raised").Range("A8")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set startingRange = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

Set sht = Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("1-Data")
Set StartCell = Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("1-Data").Range("A8")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set copyRange = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requisitions Raised").startingRange.Value = Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("1-Data").copyRange.Value
```

I've also tried the below to no avail

```vb
Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("1-Data").copyRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requisitions Raised").startingRange
```

What's causing the error? Is there a better copying solution?

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SO. To copy ranges, both ranges must be same size (must contain same quantity of cells). Are  `copyRange` and `startingRange` the same size?

Comment: Does this code even compile for you? You currently `Set` your `Range` objects, called `startingRange` and `copyRange`, and then you try to use it as a member of the worksheet. Just `startingRange.Value = copyRange.Value` would be correct syntax. You must also take into consideration the above comment by @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns.

Comment: Maybe another piece of advise, try to use meaningfull seperate variable names instead of re-using the same. Gets confusing quickly =)

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns No, there is instances where the ranges will be  a different size. I'm assuming there is a much better way to copy in that use case?

Comment: @JvdV The code compiles but it does not have the expected behavior that I thought would play out. Clearly Ranges aren't the way to go based on what Foxfire has said. The use of variable names was to stop the creation of more variables by reassigning the previously used.

Comment: Not sure, but looking at your code, it looks like you want to copy the `CurrentRegion` from A8 in worksheet `1-Data` into A8 from worksheet `Requisitions Raised`. And for this, I strongly suggest you to clear the destination range if possible (I Mean deleting old values, or you will be mixing new and old values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you currently `Set` your `Range` object, but then try to use them as members of the `Worksheet`, which would (at least for me) result into a compile error.

Instead of copy/paste, I would advise a dynamic `Value` transfer. As per @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns also said; you need equal sized `Range` object (or arrays). So therefor I included a `Resize` of `Range("A8")`. Try the following:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requisitions Raised")
Set sht2 = Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("1-Data")

lr = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lc = sht2.Cells(8, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

sht1.Cells(8, 1).Resize(lr - 7, lc).Value = sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(8, 1), sht2.Cells(lr, lc)).Value
```

As you can see I used also two different variables for `Worksheet`. Not per se really meaningfull names, but it helps to distinquish. I guess it's a personal preference.

Comment: I thought sheet variable names are good.. it gives you sheet names in minimalist way :D

Comment: Seems to work, thank you! I'm going to spend some time breaking it down to try and understand it.